How do we go back and forth between cogsci.stackexchange.com and meta.cogscie.stackexchange?
There used to be a link from main site to meta. The other way around is not there. Now there are no links either way. How can I get from the main site to meta?

Click on the Stack Exchange logo in the top left and this should bring up an option to select cogsci meta.

Or you can just go to http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com
